# angular - access array which is outside of ngOnInit()

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

there is a array called numbers in

```
export class MyphotographsComponent implements OnInit { 
  numbers =[]
}
```

after that 'numbers' array i have onNgInit(){}. In this have a function. From this function, i want to push a variable to the array outside of NgOnInit. i tried 'this.numbers.push[i]' which dint work. Need some help on this please.

Below is my sample code

```
 export class MyphotographsComponent implements OnInit {

 numbers= [];

 ngOnInit() {

    function loadImages() {
      this.numbers.push[1]
    }

    loadImages();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems a problem with the contextual aspect of `this`. Try to put the  `loadImages` function outside `ngOnInit`:

```
export class MyphotographsComponent implements OnInit {

    numbers= [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadImages();
    }

    private loadImages() {
        this.numbers.push[1]
    }

}
```

Or write `loadImages` as arrow function:

```
export class MyphotographsComponent implements OnInit {

    numbers= [];

    ngOnInit() {
        const loadImages = () => this.numbers.push[1];
        loadImages();
    }
}
```